# Content fade out/fade in & css change without page reload using JQuery,HTML & CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadein, reload

Hi I am stuck on this.

I want to achieve a jquery script that will fade out my content div,
update the css file and fade in the new content WITHOUT RELOADING THE PAGE.

Here is the code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function()    {

//handle menu clicks
$('ul.navlist li a, .actlogo-link').click(function()    {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#home-container').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#main-container').load(page, function(){
                $('#home-container').fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

HTML CODE

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Sparks Production Services &bull; File Not Found</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="main-container">
<ul class="navlist">
<li><a href="index.html"><b>Home</b></a></li>
<li><a href="hello.html">Hello</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="home-container" style="height: 100px; margin-top:15px;">
 <h1 align="center" style="padding-top:10px;">Whoops! This is embarrassing.</h1>
 <h3 align="center" style="padding-top:10px;">Sorry, the page you are after cannot be found.         </h3>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Tamizh HTML Added :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/preventdefault/)

```
$('ul.navlist li a, .actlogo-link').click(function(e)    {
e.preventDefault();
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#home-container').fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('#main-container').load(page, function(){
                $('#home-container').fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```